# How may I use other server features on Windows Home Server without breaking it?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, windows-home-server, team-foundation-server

I am hoping to run some virtual machines, IIS, SQL Server, MOSS, and Team Foundation Server on my HP MediaSmart Server 495, probably not all at the same time. There is a frightening warning message when I remote into the server telling me that I should use the WHS Console. What is the best way to run these without breaking the existing services of WHS? Would performance be a serious problem given that that it uses an Intel Celeron with 2 G of RAM?

Comment: Yes, performance will take a knock if you install things like IIS and SQL Server. I think you're playing with fire.

Comment: As Randolph pointed out - performance will be a problem.  I had some of this stuff running on a more powerful machine (not WHS, but it doesn't matter) and the performance was so-so.  If you install all of this you'll *most likely* bring the machine down to its knees.  Those services aren't lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly login to the Windows 2003 interface rather than use the WHS console.  I don't have experience with install MOSS or SQL, etc but it wouldn't hurt to check out [We Got Served](http://www.wegotserved.com/) and see if someone else has done it.  They are a good resource for WHS tips and tricks.

Comment: I also regularly login using remote desktop (almost every day.)  The warning is more to help prevent less knowledgeable users from breaking something.  +1 for suggesting We Got Served - very good WHS resource where I find most of my WHS answers.